# Robocopy Move Select Folders and Content Using .txt File Input While Preserving Timestamps

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I want to MOVE select folders and content (subfolders and files) from the Source directory to the Destination directory using a .txt file to read-in the select folder names.

I have tried running from multiple machines.

I have tried taking Ownership of folders and files.

I have tried giving Full Control to 'Everyone'.

I deleted and recreated the src and dst folders and content.

I tried removing all extra options after "/MOVE /E".

```
gc "C:\testText.txt" | % { robocopy "C:\testSrc" "C:\testDst" 
$_ /MOVE /E /R:3 /W:15 /MT:128 /log+:C:\log.txt /v /tee }
```

I expect this script to read-in the folder names from the .txt file for the select folders I want to move (along with their content and timestamps) from the Source directory to the Destination directory.

Script is only copying the folders and subfolders but not files. Nor is it deleting the source data, but I imagine that has to do with the original problem of not being able to copy the files.

**testText.txt Content (These are names of folders residing in the Source Directory):**

0000003000
0000003001
0000003002

**Log Output (Same output for each of the folders listed in testText.txt):**

Started : Wednesday, May 8, 2019 12:33:27 PM
   Source : C:\testSrc\
     Dest : C:\testDst\

```
Files : 0000003000
```

Options : /V /TEE /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /MOVE /MT:128 /R:3 /W:15

---

---

```
           Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
Dirs :         4         4         1         0         0         0
Files :        0         0         0         0         0         0
Bytes :        0         0         0         0         0         0
Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
Ended : Wednesday, May 8, 2019 12:33:27 PM
```

Comment: [1] what is in the log? [2] what is in the file that you are piping to your robocopy call?

Comment: Added requested info to my post.

Comment: Actually I just noticed the log has '1' in Skipped column, normally that reads '4'

Comment: your command is telling robocopy to use a _folder_ as a file specification. that will NOT work. the 3 leading options are `source dir`, `dest dir`, and `file specification`. you cannot use a folder name for the 3rd option. [*grin*]

Comment: Ya know, I was actually thinking the same thing but wasn't sure because the logs indicate that it recognizes they are directories and copied them anyway. But I guess that option doesn't have the ability of recursion since it is built for files. Do you have any suggestions as to going about this task? ForEach-Object Loop?

Comment: why don't you use the dir names as the source? that seems to make more sense to me ... [*grin*]

Comment: I tried that but wouldn't work with the current method. I got it working with a foreach loop using the dir names as the source for a "/MIR /DCOPY:T" because I needed all timestamps preserved and then "rm -R" for folder deletion. Posting code in answer. Thanks for the nudges in the right direction Lee_Dailey, sometimes the simple act of convo triggers the solution :)

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have kinda-sorta helped. you may want to look up "rubber duck debugging" some time ... [*grin*]

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't know there was a name for it, especially something so nonsensical. We can close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This Works.

```
foreach($line in 
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\testText.txt")) { 

robocopy "C:\testSrc\$line" "C:\testDst\$line" /MIR /DCOPY:T /E /R:3 /W:15 
/MT:128 /log+:C:\Log.txt /v /tee

rm -R "C:\testSrc\$line"

}
```